# How to solve Unknown label type: 'unknown' in decision trees Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to decision and trying to make a decision tree from a Review dataframe that has scores so far I tried this bu it is giving me

```
X = ndf.drop('Score', axis=1) 
y = ndf['Score'] 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42, test_size=0.30)
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

all the values in ndf['Score'] are either 1 or 0. And I am getting the error  Unknown label type: 'unknown' when I try to run the last line. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of your labels (`y_train` and `y_test`) are in a single type only (either `int` or `string`).

For your case, `int` might be an appropriate type for the label, convert it to `int` if you see the type of `Score` is `object` when you do `ndf.info()`

```py
# Add below line to convert the typt to `int`
xdf['Score'] = xdf['Score'].astype('int')

# Your code should be working fine now
X = ndf.drop('Score', axis=1) 
y = ndf['Score'] 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42, test_size=0.30)
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

In general, we should always apply the appropriate type for columns, not just for `DecisionTreeClassifier`.